# need help when i try to custom hide password kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I want user write "A" for example and see "b", I want some different way with custom keyboard for the app

this what I tried today but not worked

```
import android.text.method.PasswordTransformationMethod
import android.view.View

class passit: PasswordTransformationMethod() {
    override fun getTransformation(source: CharSequence?, view: View?): CharSequence {
return turnit(source!!)   }
    class turnit(val s:CharSequence):CharSequence{
        override val length: Int=  s.length

        override fun get(index: Int): Char {
return 'f'      }

        override fun subSequence(startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int): CharSequence {
            return s.subSequence(0,s.length)      }


    }
}
```

mian give the error: transformationMethod of type cannot be invoked as a function

```
Petitionadd.transformationMethod(passit())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function on `TextView` you're trying to call is `setTransformationMethod`:

```
textView.setTransformationMethod(Passit())
```

Which you can also access from Kotlin as a property:

```
textView.transformationMethod = Passit()
```

Comment: it is an edit text, not textView i want to custom hiding string

Comment: `EditText` inherits from `TextView`, so you can use transformation methods on them the same way :)

Comment: thank you for your fast answer, I did that and it say transformationMethod of type cannot be invoked as a function